# Microsoft.Graph.Core create subscription "Access denied"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-functions-core-tools

Following [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/azure-functions), I'm able to get a "subscription" on my Azure Function to a users mailbox.

However when I modify it to try to access a users onedrive, I'm able to access their files in the app, but when attempting to subscribe for a webhook I get the error below. I verified my token has Files.ReadWrite.All permission so I don't understand what I'm missing.

```
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.327Z] Executed 'SetDocSubscription' (Failed, Id=01410f60-0954-4e37-b9aa-2940cf9d0a17, Duration=2177ms)
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.330Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: SetDocSubscription. Microsoft.Graph.Core: Code: ExtensionError
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.331Z] Message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access denied]
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.332Z] Inner error:
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.333Z]      AdditionalData:
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.334Z]      date: 2020-11-19T16:17:11
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.335Z]      request-id: ccd648e7-b3fc-43f6-b1c5-481cbb5dcab6
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.336Z]      client-request-id: ccd648e7-b3fc-43f6-b1c5-481cbb5dcab6
[2020-11-19T16:17:12.337Z] ClientRequestId: ccd648e7-b3fc-43f6-b1c5-481cbb5dcab6
```

...additional detail, calling function looks like this:

```
                // Create a new subscription object
                var subscription = new Subscription
                {
                    ChangeType = "updated",
                    NotificationUrl = $"{notificationHost}/api/DocsNotify",
                    Resource = $"/users/{payload.UserId}/drive/root/",
                    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
                    ClientState = Notify.ClientState
                };

                // POST /subscriptions
                var createdSubscription = await graphClient.Subscriptions
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(subscription);
                
                return new OkObjectResult(createdSubscription);
```

Comment: I am suspecting you're exceeding the limits here. When any limit (it can be Azure AD resource limitation as well) is exceeded, attempts to create a subscription will result in an error response - 403 Forbidden. You can see the above error. In it you will see the message property which will explain which limit has been exceeded.

Comment: Here's the related doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

Answer (score 0):

- I am suspecting you're exceeding the limits here. When any limit (it can be Azure AD resource limitation as well) is
  exceeded, attempts to create a subscription will result in an error
  response - 403 Forbidden.
- You can see the above error. In your
  scenario, you will see the message property which will explain which
  limit has been exceeded.
- Here's the related [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks).